# injecting UINibExternalObjects to an self initialzied ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, nib, viewcontroller, viewdidload

I want to navigate from one ViewController to another. As part of this I want to
pass the ViewController I want to navigate to some information. I encapsulated the
information into an Object that I want to hook up as an external object with the target
viewController.

I created the external Object inside IB gave it the identifier I referenced in the NSDictionary that is passed to the NibLoading method.

```
NSArray*    topLevelObjs = nil;
NSMutableDictionary* options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableDictionary* config = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

id detailImageVC = [[SelectedImageModalViewController alloc] init];
SelectedImageModalModel* selectImageModalModel = [[SelectedImageModalModel alloc] init];
selectImageModalModel.imageName = @"img@2x.png";

[config setValue:selectImageModalModel forKey:@"SelectImageModalModel"];
[options setValue:config forKey:UINibExternalObjects];

topLevelObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectedImageModalViewController" owner:detailImageVC options:options];
if ([topLevelObjs count] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Warning! Could not substitute proxy objects in xib file.\n");
    return;
}

[appDelegate.navigationController presentModalViewController:detailImageVC animated:YES];

[options release];
[config release];
[selectImageModalModel release];
[detailImageVC release];
```

What I expected was, that after I called presentModalViewController:animated: I would receive a call to viewDidLoad on the very same detailImageVC with my external objects 
connected.

Instead neither happens. viewWillApear: will get called, but the detailImageVC won't hold my external reference.

Any idea, hind or comment is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` will be called if only ViewController loaded the view itself.

For example; `initWithNibName` does not load the view, it just sets the nib name. When ViewController needs its view in some future point and if there is no view in `ViewController.view` then ViewController will load view like you did AND THEN INVOKE `viewDidLoad` itself.

Your code loads the view of ViewController itself. So you should call the `viewDidLoad` method in your code like this:

```
topLevelObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectedImageModalViewController" owner:detailImageVC options:options];
if (topLevelObjs.count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Warning! Could not substitute proxy objects in xib file.\n");
    return;
} else {
    [detailImageVC viewDidLoad];
}
```

If your `detailImageVC` does not hold your external object then you should check your nib file for `IBOutlet` bindings and your `SelectedImageModalViewController` for corresponding `@property`. If property is not strong like `@property(nonatomic, strong)` on ARC, or, is not reatin on Non-ARC like `@property(nonatomic, retain)` then it will not hold your object after awaking from nib.